# Handling firebase notifications taking into account the presence of firebase user whether he is online or not

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

My problem is that whenever the reciever goes offline  and then comes back online after some time he is supposed to recieve all the chat notification that were sent to him during that period but it only recieves the latest one when reciever comes back online.Is there any way it could be solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cloud functions to store users' notifications in firestore into 2 lists (read & unread) before pushing them to him. And when he's back online, make your app push the notifications from the unread list.

Comment: I built a firebase user presence system using flutter.My first problem is that when the app is killed it marks the user as offline even when the intenet connection is on. I want to display the notifications to user.My second problem is when the user kills the app and then turns off the intenet connection i want to listen to that change and update the user status... but the defaut firebase behaviour is that whenever user kills the it marks the user offline. Is there any workaround this problem